# How to install armhf snap packages in arm64 architecture?

Tags: snap, raspberrypi, 21.04, arm

On a fresh install of Ubuntu desktop 21.04 in arm64, I have added the `armhf` architecture via `dpkg`. When installing `.deb` packages, I do not encounter any difficulties. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work with snap packages, as `snap install` always indicates, that the respective packages are not available in my architecture, but only in `armhf`.

I have not found a way to add an `armhf` flag to the snap installer yet, is there a solution for this, or do I have to set up the Raspberry Pi in 32bit architecture?